# Как отсортировать стек?

Tags: c#, коллекции, стек

Стек содержит различные объекты классов. Реализовал IComparable для сортировки, но все равно не до конца понимаю как отсортировать. Нужно что-то вроде List.Sort(), но не могу найти.

Comment: Все вытащить, отсортировать, положить обратно.

Comment: Может вам от стека отказаться вообще? У стека другое назначение.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я бы с радостью, но не могу - задание такое.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо, сделал.

Comment: Какой стек имеется ввиду? Стандартный класс [Stack<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) или какая-то своя реализация?

Comment: @raspberry367, напишите ответ.